# How to Sum One Column over Three Rows?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have table that I want to sum 3 rows of one column how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly - you should use the SUM() function

```
SELECT SUM(the_column) 
FROM the_table 
WHERE condition-to-get-your-three-rows
```

A "WHERE" clause will allow to specify which 3 rows you want to be summed up. Some examples of "WHERE" clauses are below:

```
WHERE row_id < 3
```

or

```
WHERE active = 'Yes'
```

So the above statement may look like

```
SELECT SUM(the_column) 
FROM the_table 
WHERE active = 'Yes'
```

Comment: how can i get those three rows

Comment: you need to write a WHERE clause (as shown above). This clause needs to contain a condition. I've added examples to my answer above.
If you can specify what 3 rows in your table you want to be summed up, I can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
SUM(table.column1) + SUM(table.column2) + SUM(table.column3) 
FROM table
```